# Bezier curves and centering of plot in the page

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I try to draw a Bezier curve:

[image]

My MWE below:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
clip=false,
ylabel={$P$}, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=east},
xlabel={$T$}, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
ticks=none,
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
]
\draw[thick] (axis cs:0.05,1) .. controls (axis cs:2,0.7) and (axis cs:-0.8,0.1) .. (axis cs:0.9,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

But the picture is not centered horizontally, because the contros are far beyond the boundaries of the coordinate plane. How can I draw a picture with the correct centering on the page?

Comment: Can't you just have `clip=true`, which is default, or do you need `clip=false` for some other reason?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I need need `clip=false` for some other reason.

Comment: add `overlay` option to the `\draw`

Comment: @percusse Yes, thank you, `overlay` option helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can clip your picture (`\framebox` added only to see the effect):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\framebox{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (10,10); %here - PS
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = middle,
clip=false,
ylabel={$P$}, ylabel style={at=(current axis.above origin), anchor=east},
xlabel={$T$}, xlabel style={at=(current axis.right of origin), anchor=west},
xmin=0, xmax=1,
ymin=0, ymax=1,
ticks=none,
width=10cm,
height=10cm,
]
\draw[thick] (axis cs:0.05,1) .. controls (axis cs:2,0.7) and (axis cs:-0.8,0.1) .. (axis cs:0.9,0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]